# Prove that if $A_i$ are countable sets then $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is a countable set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Consider the following theorem

> Let $\{A_1,A_2,...\}$ be a countable family of sets such that each
> $A_i$ is a countable set. Then $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is a
> countable set.

Here is a proof I saw in a book

Let $A_n=\{a_1^n,a_2^n,...\}$ for $n=1,2,...$, and $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Also, let $B=\{2^k\cdot 3^n:k,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Now define $f:B\to A$ by $f(2^k\cdot 3^n)=a_k^n$. Then $f$ maps $B$ onto $A$, and hence $A$ is a countable set by Theorem 2.5.

Note that the cited Theorem 2.5 says the following statements are equivalent

(i) "$A$ is countable"

(ii) "there exists a subset $B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ and a function $f:B\to A$ that is onto".

(iii) "there exists a function $g:A\to\mathbb{N}$ is one-to-one"

In the context of the proof, for each $a_k^n$ there is some natural number of form $m=2^k\cdot 3^n$ associated with it such that $f(m)=a_k^n$.

How do we know that for $a_{k_1}^{n_1}$ and $a_{k_2}^{n_2}$ we don't have $2^{k_1}\cdot 3^{n_1}=2^{k_2}\cdot 3^{n_2}$?

If we do prove this, then I believe I understand that the proof follows from (ii) above.

Comment: Unique factorization of integers

Answer (score 2):

Let $m,n,j,k \in \mathbf{Z}^+$. We will prove that $2^m 3^n = 2^j 3^k$ if and only if $m = j$ and $n = k$. First, assume that $2^m 3^n = 2^j 3^k$ for some positive integers $m,n,j,k$. Suppose, without loss of generality, that $m \le j$. Then, we can divide both sides by $2^m$ to get $3^n = 2^{j - m} 3^k$. Now we split the problem into cases:

Case 1. Suppose that $n \le k$. Then, we can divide both sides by $3^n$ to get $1 = 2^{j - m} 3^{k - n}$. This equation only holds true only when $j - m = k - n = 0$. In other words, when $j = m$ and $k = n$.

Case 2. Suppose that $k \le n$. Then, we can divide both sides by $3^k$ to get $3^{n - k} = 2^{j - m}$. If you trust me that $3^{n - k}$ and $2^{j - m}$ share no factors, then you will see that this equation only holds true when $n - k = 0$ and $j - m = 0$, exactly when $n = k$ and $j = m$.

The reverse implication is trivial. Hopefully this helps.